# Strange coordinates when rendering to framebuffer with texture

Tags: opengl

I'm making 2D game with large-pixel graphics. To achieve this effect I'm rendering all images to framebuffer with texture 2 times smaller than my window. And then, I'm rendering this texture to window using quad (`{{-1,-1},{1,-1},{1,1},{-1,1}}`).

This works fine, but coordinate system when rendering to texture is a bit strange. For example, when I use

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
glVertex2f(-0.75, -0.75);
glEnd();
```

It renders 2x2 point. I would expect this point to be at `(win_w * 1/8, win_h * 7/8)` 
but whis point is at `(win_w * 1/4, win_h * 3/4)`.

If I change framebuffer texture size from `((win_w + 1) / 2, (win_h + 1) / 2)` (2 times smaller than my screen)
to `((win_w + 3) / 4, (win_h + 3) / 4)` (4 times smaller than my screen) that point is now has 4x4 size and it is at `(win_w * 1/2, win_h * 1/2)` (center of window).

I think this is incorrect. AFAIK, framebuffer coordinate system does not depend on framebuffer texture size; `1,1` is a top-right corner on any texture size, right?

There is no transformation matrixes or sometring like this, so OpenGL must not transform my coordinates.

I still can render with this strange coordinate system, but I don't understand why it works this way.

So, question is: i want to render vertices is same place inside window with any framebuffer texture size. Is it possible? (I don't want to use trasformation matrixes inside shaders, because it should work without them. I hope there is another solutions.)

Shaders:

```
// Vertex:
#version 430
in layout(location = 0) vec2 pos;
out vec2 vPos;
void main()
{
    vPos = pos;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos.x, pos.y, 0, 1);
}

// Fragment:
#version 430
uniform layout(location = 0) sampler2D tex;
in vec2 vPos;
out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    color = texture(tex, (vPos + 1) / 2);
}
```

Comment: Just from the symptoms, it sounds like you might be missing the `glViewport()` call before starting to render to the FBO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. (Thanks to @RetoKoradi.) Now my code looks like this:

```
glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
/// Switch shaders and framebuffer
DrawQuadWithTexture();
glViewport(0, 0, 400, 300);
/// Switch shaders and framebuffer
DrawAllStuff();
```